# In KDIFF3 How to automatically overwrite any whitespace conflict for all files

Tags: kdiff3

In Kdiff3, when comparing between two directories with multiple files and folders and there are multiple white space conflicts in each file. I have to go through each file and manually click on "merge" and choose "Choose (A or B) for all unsolved white space conflicts".

Is there a way that I can apply that rule on the entire project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Kdiff3` provides 2 mechanisms for dealing with white space only differences in files. The first is the default operation of `kdif3` providing a summary column in 2-file view as well as providing underscore visualization of whitespace difference. When lines differ only in the amount of white space this can be seen in the summary column on the left side of the display.

For automatic handling of whitespace differences on a file-by-file basis, in `Settings-> Merge -> White space 2(3) file merge default:` (choose either `manual`, `A`, of `B`) Selecting `A` will automatically select select the first file when the two files only differ by whitespace.